# Getting error while cloning any thing from git in mac

Tags: git, macos, github, git-clone

Whenever I am trying to clone any repository from GitHub or bitbucket getting below error. I have updated my OS also. Could anyone please help me? I am using Mac

Error Information:

> git-remote-https(640,0x7fffe1c733c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=52428800000000000) failed (error code=3)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>    **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   git-remote-https(640,0x7fffe1c733c0) malloc:**  mach_vm_map(size=52428800000000000) failed (error code=3)
>    **error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 52428800000000000 bytes)

Comment: "52428800000000000 bytes" suggests your Git installation is broken.  Did you build Git yourself?  Or install it from somewhere?  Where?

Comment: I downloaded it from https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: Does anyone face this problem. ? I have searched a lot but not able to find any perfect solution .